# AWS Appsync subscription reliable delivery?

Tags: graphql, aws-appsync

We were thinking of using aws appsync for communicating alerts/messages to mobile and web apps using graphql subscription feature. I tried a small example in nodejs using appsync javascript sdk based on tutorial https://docs.aws.amazon.com/appsync/latest/devguide/building-a-client-app-node.html. This is my first time doing graphql and appsync. 
Since they use MQTT over websockets, what is QoS used for subscribing? 1, 2

When we use `appsyncclient.subscribe` Is it our responsibility to verify if duplicate data is coming into the `next` callback or is it guaranteed based on ID.